# Video-JS + Colorbox, loading dynamic videos

Tags: html5-video, colorbox, video.js

Having an issue that has been frustrating me the last few days.

I have some videos on a site that are loaded dynamically from sitecore, and display on a page with thumbnail images. When you click those images you are taken to a lightbox with the video.

The problem is, the video plays in Chrome, Firefox and IE8 -, but not IE9 +. I thought it may be an encoding issue, but I have converted this video so many times to every format available to the web to no avail.

I am setting the plugin to load the video as flash first, then if flash isn't available, load as html5. This will clear all worries in terms of browser support of HTML5 video.

I was thinking that it may be the lightbox and videoJS plugin fighting with each other, or the fact that i am hiding videos and showing them, which i know can sometimes cause issues. I have decided to use a different lightbox, and people seem to have said that colorbox is a decent one to use with videoJS, especially since it has some built in callbacks onLoad.

On to the problem and the code:

**The problem:**

This lightbox is working, but videoJS seems to throw a few errors when i try and reset the player, which is breaking the videos in IE since its such a dumb browser.

As you can see in the demo link at the bottom, the videos play in IE just fine when they are just set on the page, but when you open the lightbox by pressing "vid1" or "vid2" you are riddled with console errors and the videos no longer play.

**The code:**

HTML + jScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>

        <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>



        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .hide {
                display: none;   
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".inline", this).colorbox({ 
                    inline: true, 
                    rel: 'videohook', 
                    width: '650px',
                    onLoad: function() {

                        //grab the video ID and store it
                        var vidID = $(this).attr("data-vidID"); 

                        //Reset the video players 
                        videojs.players = {};

                        //set the videoJS player for this video.
                        videojs(vidID); 
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>

        <a rel="videohook" data-vidID="my_video_1" class="inline" href="#video_1">vid 1</a>
        <a rel="videohook" data-vidID="my_video_2" class="inline" href="#video_2">vid 2</a>

        <div id="video_1" class="video">
            <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
             preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster=""
             data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]}'>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type='video/ogv'>
            </video>
        </div>

        <div id="video_2" class="video">
            <video id="my_video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
             preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster=""
             data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]}'>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type='video/ogv'>
            </video>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**Console errors im getting:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'vjs_getProperty'
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

Go here to see the errors for yourself: http://kodistro.com

Answer (score 1):

In this case, my solution is to inject the video tag HTML into the lightbox content (when opening) and then call videojs().

So, in pseudo-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".inline", this).colorbox({ 
                inline: true, 
                rel: 'videohook', 
                width: '650px',
                height: '274', //the size most be fixed
                onLoad: function() {
                    var appendVideo1 = '<video id="my_video_1"......> </video>'; //insert the <video> tag. Note.Remove attribute data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]}'                         
                    $("video_1").append(appendVideo1);
                },
                onComplete: function() {
                    videojs(my_video_1); //initialize video-js
                },
                onClosed: function() {
                    videojs(my_video_1).dispose(); //destroy video-js
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <a rel="videohook" data-vidID="my_video_1" class="inline" href="#video_1">vid 1</a>
    <div id="video_1" class="video">           
    </div>
```